# Javascript Module Design

Tags: javascript, object, module

I was wondering if someone could explain the difference between these two JavaScript modules. I have been trying to learn how to design javascript modules by reading some underscore.js and jQuery source code, amongst others and have noticed these two patterns.

Example 1

```
(function() {

    var _this = this;

    _this.VERSION = '0.1';

}).call(this);
```

Example 2

```
(function(_this) {

    _this.VERSION = '0.1';

}(this));
```

Comment: In the first one, `_this === this`, while in the second one `this` might have a different value. And please omit that line `var _this = _this;`

Answer (score 1):

`call(obj[, arg[, arg[, arg[, ...]]]])` runs function in `obj` context, `function () {}(obj)` will run function in current context passing `obj` in arguments. In this particular example there is no difference - both examples will do same thing. For some people it is just cleaner to run anonymous function with `call` or `apply` instead of just `()` and I think here it is the case.

In second example line with `var _this = _this;` is useless, `_this` is already defined within scope and that line is redefining already existing variable with same value (so its even incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 explicitly sets the value of the `this` variable within the function.

In Example 2 the function does not care about the value of `this`. It rather expects an argument that it can work with. You also could say that it does not rely on the value of `this`. An advantage of this pattern is that by the name of the parameter it can be made clear what you want (`window`, `myObjectContext` ...).

In your specific case it does not make a difference. But if the function contained code that made actual use of `this`, e.g. `this.myObject = {}`, it **could** make a difference, because `this` could have a different value in each case. But to be true, someone using the second pattern would never reference `this` within the function.

Comment: When you say someone using the second pattern wouldn't reference ```this```, do you mean the way I have used a variable ```_this```? What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: In your case it means that **inside the function** you would always use `_this`, not `this`. I would give `_this` another name, though, one that reflects its value / purpose more clearly.